# Ionic 3 / Angular 4 integration

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm new to angular 4. I'm a bit lost regarding how to use the ionic framework to do the mobile.

My goal is to build an app to use on Android devices, and also on a laptop.

Should I develop 1st the angular app then try to package it with ionic, or should I start my project straight with both ionic 3/Angular 4 projects (like in this article: https://www.djamware.com/post/58e657b680aca764ec903c2d/ionic-3-and-angular-4-mobile-app-example)

Thank you!

Comment: If you want it to be an ionic app, just start immediately with an ionic app

Comment: Please join my Ionic 3 chatroom - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153499/ionic-3

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Ionic is in sync with the latest version of Angular. Angular is packaged with Ionic, so you are constrained to the version contained therein. I'm mostly saying this from the perspective of having developed only Ionic 1 apps. It may be different for Ionic 2, so my comment is cautionary.

If you have never used Ionic for any mobile app development, I would personally skip Ionic 1 (which is on the older AngularJS) and just familiarize yourself with Ionic 2.

Comment: `Angular is packaged with Ionic` was the case with v1.x

Answer (score 1):

Ionic uses Angular-Directives. Angular itself is not used to build apps but is used by frameworks of app development such as the ionic framework. So just go ahead and make your app using ionic. You will use angular in your mobile app.

Notice that your app gets wrapped in a native-container for it to be able to communicate with the mobile architecture of the device. You probably want to use something different for your Website instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to build an app for mobile (android) as well, then I would suggest to kick start using ionic itself. As Ionic 3.x has its own navigation system and components which you can share with a desktop version of the application (especially the [Split](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/) panel). If you go ahead with simple angular differently you need a framework who does these things for you. 
However, certainly, you might come across accessing native APIs (plugins) which will not all work on a desktop. So better follow the mobile-first approach. 
checkout [this article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/07/23/some-initial-thoughts-on-building-desktop-apps-with-ionic-and-electron) which might help you to share code between desktop and mobile with Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [official Ionic website](https://ionicframework.com/framework):

> Ionic provides a complete mobile toolkit, built for web developers.
>
> Everything you need to start creating fully functional mobile apps in just minutes.

So if you know Angular, HTML, and CSS, you can go ahead and develop an Ionic project which can be run in Browser as well as on devices (Android, iOS).
You need to create builds for running on devices and upload them to respective stores, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 3 We are packaged with Angular 4  so that we can use angular 4 directives .We can reuse most of the Angular 4 code in ionic 3 App ,However if U want to deploy  ionic 3 App as android or hybrid u can deploy it . however U can  also deploy as web but design and other will be from ionic  3. If u want to use material design of Angular in Ionic 3 app. U can By include that package